# hasAndBelongsToMany problem by changing the condition in the model

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I select Blog entries by changing hasAndBelongsToMany conditions on the fly, it doesnt work anymore for me with cakephp 1.3.
Strange problem cause it was working fine with 1.2, in the model i test it by putting a condition with a static id to see what happen, `(Tag.name => 'libros')`. but it pass though the hasAndBelongsToMany condition. Bring me whatever results.

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Tag' =>
                       array('className'  => 'Tag',
                             'joinTable'  => 'blogs_tags',
                             'foreignKey' => 'blog_id',
                             'associationForeignKey'=> 'tag_id',
                             'conditions' => '',
                             'order'      => '',
                             'limit'      => '',
                             'unique'       => true,
                             'finderSql'  => '',
                             'deleteQuery'=> ''
                       )
```

in the controller

```
$this->Blog->bindModel(array(
                  'hasAndBelongsToMany' => array(
                        'Tag' => array('conditions'=>array('Tag.name'=>'libros'))
            )));
            $this->Blog->find('all');
```

Now i dont have mysql error anymore , but i have others records with others results. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a correct database structure, must use this=

```
$this->Blog->bindModel(array(
                        'hasOne' => array(
                              'BlogsTag',
                              'FilterTag' => array(
                                    'className' => 'Tag',
                                    'foreignKey' => false,
                                    'conditions' => array('FilterTag.id = BlogsTag.tag_id')
                  ))));
            $data = $this->Blog->find('all', array(
                        'fields' => array('Blog.*'),
                        'conditions'=>array('FilterTag.name'=>'libros')
            ));
```

you can read more about this at :
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM